# Will placing a shopping cart system in a directory other than the root of the site affect SEO/google rankings?

Tags: seo, directory, shopping-cart, ranking, opencart

If all opencart files are placed within a directory called open cart, will the products have less 'searchability' than if placed within the root of the domain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to keywords in URLs, the suggestion is to always place them as close as possible to the domain. So if you are spacing them out a bit, there is a possibility that it may be slightly less searchable. Could you rename the directory "products" or something more appropriate to your business or product?

Answer (score 0):

No. The contents will be indexed as well as the files were in the main root. Obviously this is because you've not many nested folders.

Anyway you can call the directory with a more SEO name like "shop", "e-shop" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like /store/ is more preferable if you have to do that really, but honestly it won't make all that much difference having the one directory name added. Google will still spider the site, and find your content.

Also, while there is some benefit to your SEO friendly URL's, it's just one small factor of the bigger picture of SEO in general. It's also worth mentioning that you should be using a google base feed too to improve your product visibility in the SERPS, as they become more and more used